# Changing brightness of the Macbook(Pro) keyboard backlight

Tags: python, macos, hardware

Programaticly, how can I modify the brightness of the backlit keyboard on a Macbook or Macbook Pro using Python?

Answer (score 9):

Amit Singh discusses these undocumented APIs in this [online bonus chapter](https://web.archive.org/web/20200103164052/https://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter10/light/), but does so using C -- I'm not sure if a Python extension exists to do the same work from Python, perhaps as part of PyObjC (otherwise, such an extension would have to be written -- or `ctypes` used to access the shared C libraries directly from Python [shudder;-)]).