# how can I change the brightness of the keyboard backlight

Tags: macos, brightness, backlight

I just the want to change the brightness of the backlit by programming.
If should use the private API, never mind, just want to finish the function.
Anyone can tell me which API should I to use?

Answer (score 0):

Might want to check out this article: http://www.osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter10/light/.

It was mentioned in [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991813/changing-brightness-of-the-macbookpro-keyboard-backlight) that might be related to this question.

Please note that the article (at the time of writing [2006],) does say:

> There Are No Published Motion/Light Sensor APIs

Comment: but i see a bundle called backlight visualizer can do this,really cool

Comment: This might be the link @RetVal is talking about: http://www.keindesign.de/stefan/Web/Sites/iWeb/Site/iSpazz.html  But... do be aware of the warning at the bottom of the page that says: "Oh, and before I forget: No warranty whatsoever. If the display flicker mode eventually kills your computer’s backlight, it’s not my problem - sorry."  ;-)